When the direction of causation can plausiblely run in either direction, is there a good stat approach to distinguishing relative strength?
I am interested in an instance where it is plausible that ideology influences economic outcome, and also that economic outcomes influence ideology. Assuming that I have good and relavent measures of each, and assuming moreover (but somewhat more questionably) that there is no third factor that accounts for both, is there any statistical way of determining the relative importance of the two directions of causation?
This is a quasi-experiment based on historical data, so I have no opportunity to rerun events with proper randomization.

If you have good timeseries data of each, the standard approach would likely be granger causality or transfer entropy. Note that these approaches are not necessarily measures of true causality, but I think trying these would give you a nice start on your problem.
